# using value from previous object property function

Tags: javascript

Cannot use value from previous object property function `starting();` when trying to combine in output below; getting `NaN` for `timeTaken();` function. Presumably `starting` isn't reporting within that function, any suggestions?

```
  starting : function() {
     return this.slow * this.driveTime + " mph ";
  },
  timeTaken : function() { 
     return this.starting / this.driveTime + " seconds ";
  },
```

---

```
document.getElementById("car").innerHTML = car.starting() +  car.timeTaken();
```

*Should I rather try to nest both functions in same one function? I'm open to more optimal methods.*

---

Full object code:

```
var car = {
  cruise: "35",
  slow: "5",
  stop: "0",
  driveTime: "4",
  starting : function() {
     return this.slow * this.driveTime + " mph ";
  },
  timeTaken : function() { 
       return this.starting / this.driveTime + " seconds ";
  },
 };
```

Comment: Calling only `car.starting()` working fine?

Comment: Yes, .starting() works fine.

Comment: 2 guesses: 1. Shouldn't you make a function call in return: "return this.starting() / ...." . and the second guess, you append the 'mph' which makes the return value of the starting() to string, and try to divide the string to another string.

Comment: I thought about that, and omitted extra text and still get NaN error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because `this.starting` is a *function*. Basically what you are asking JavaScript to do is "take the `starting` function and divide it by `this.driveTime`". This is undefined.

What I'm guessing you want is something like this:

```js
var car = {
  cruise: 35,
  slow: 5,
  stop: 0,
  driveTime: 4,
  starting: function() {
    return this.slow * this.driveTime;
  },
  timeTaken: function() {
    return this.starting() / this.driveTime;
  },
  toString: function() {
    return this.starting() + " mph " + this.timeTaken() + " seconds ";
  }
};

console.log(car.toString());
console.log(car.starting());
console.log(car.timeTaken());
```

Note that I changed `starting()` and `timeTaken()` to just return numbers (rather than "x mph" or "x seconds"). This allows you to do math on the results from those functions.

I added the `toString()` function to make it easier to get a string representation of the data that I'm assuming you wanted to print out.

**EDIT:** As noted by [Peter Behr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/739028/peter-behr)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42752441/2319844), you should store `cruise`, `slow` `stop`, and `driveTime` as numbers rather than strings. I have updated my example to show this.

---

**Further Reading**

- [JavaScript data types and data structures at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures)

Comment: Thanks! so, I have to do the math within another separate function basically?

Comment: @Cage, you could think of it like that. The most important thing to look at is what each function is returning. If you return something that is a number, as I am for `starting` and `timeTaken`, you can do math on its result. Whereas if you return a string, like the `toString` function, you can only do string operations with it.

Answer (score 2):

Additionally, you're doing math on strings, which isn't a great idea. Make the object properties numbers to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

`starting`  method return a `String` so divide a `string` by a `number` will result as `NaN`